# Why does my C code print Segmentation fault: 11?

Tags: c

```
#include "stdio.h"

struct List {
   int i;
};

int main() {
    int c[5] = {3,1,2,5,4};
    struct List **list;
    printf("----%p\n",list);
    struct List one = {0};
    struct List two = {1};
    list[0] = &one;
    list[1] = &two;
    printf("One: %p\n", list[0]);
    printf("Two: %p\n", list[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

result print:

```
----0x0
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I just learned C language. what is the problem here? And then if I remove the line of "int c[5] = {3,1,2,5,4}" , the code works fine. but it prints:

```
----0x7fff5d9a99a0     (1
One: 0x7fff5d9a9978    (2
Two: 0x7fff5d9a9970    (3
```

And why is the address of "(1" different from "(2" ?

Can the “pointer to pointer” be treated as an array?

Comment: `list` is uninitialized. It is not pointing to anywhere specifically, so when you assign a value to `list[0]` your code will invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: What you need is `struct List *list[2]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have not allocated any memory to `list`, so applying index operator to it causes undefined behavior.

Fix it by allocating an array of two pointers to `list`:

```
struct List **list = malloc(2 * sizeof(List*));
```

Note that printing with `%p` requires passing `void*`:

```
printf("----%p\n", (void*)list);
...
printf("One: %p\n", (void*)list[0]);
printf("Two: %p\n", (void*)list[1]);
```

Finally, you need to free the pointer once you are done to avoid memory leaks:

```
free(list);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is due to this -

```
struct List **list;   // <--- not initialized
```

then these statements -

```
printf("----%p\n",list);
//your code
list[0] = &one;              
list[1] = &two;
```

you dereference an uninitialized pointer which causes undfined behaviour and as a result segmentation fault.

Allocate memory to `list` using `malloc`(or `calloc`) and then dereference it to store value.

Answer (score 1):

That is because of these 2 lines, or rather just 1st one.

```
list[0] = &one;
list[1] = &two;
```

You need to allocate memory for `list` before you can refer it.

Something like

```
list = malloc(sizeof(*list) * 100); //for 100 list items
```

Or create array of instead of pointer

```
struct List *list[100]; //for 100 list items
```

Answer (score 1):

`list` is never initialized (will be filled with whatever random data is on the stack) and then this random data is dereferenced as a ptr via `list[0]` and `list[1]`.
You could make `list` pt to something like an array of 10 ptrs:

```
struct List **list = (struct List **) malloc(10*sizeof(struct List*));
```